# running same script over many machines

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

I have setup a few EC2 instances, which all have a script in the home directory. I would like to run the script simultaneously across each EC2 instance, i.e. without going through a loop.

I have seen csshX for OSX for terminal interactive useage...but was wondering what the commandline code is to execute commands like

```
ssh user@ip.address . test.sh
```

to run the test.sh script across all instances since...

```
csshX user@ip.address.1 user@ip.address.2 user@ip.address.3 . test.sh
```

does not work...

I would like to do this over the commandline as I would like to automate this process by adding it into a shell script.

and for bonus points...if there is a way to send a message back to the machine sending the command that it has completed running the script that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will it be good enough to have a master shell script that runs all these things in the background?  e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
pidlist="ignorethis"
for ip in ip1 ip2
do
    ssh user@$ip . test.sh &
    pidlist="$pidlist $!" # get the process number of the last forked process
done

# Now all processes are running on the remote machines, and we want to know
# when they are done.

# (EDIT) It's probably better to use the 'wait' shell built-in; that's
# precisely what it seems to be for.
while true
do
    sleep 1
    alldead=true
    for pid in $pidlist
    do
        if kill -0 $pid > /dev/null 2>&1
        then
            alldead=false
            echo some processes alive
            break
        fi
    done
    if $alldead
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

echo all done.

it will not be exactly simultaneous, but it should kick off the remote scripts in parallel.

Comment: That doesn't really help since the test.sh script takes a long time to run and I think it doesn't start the next ssh until the first one has completed...

Comment: Are you sure?  The key here is the & at the end of the ssh line, to run the ssh call in the background.

Comment: ah...i see what you mean now...that does work thank you...so what would i need to do to see that all the processes had finished?

Comment: (after editing) This turned out to be a lot harder and uglier than I would have expected -- which probably means there's a better way.  But this worked for me on my Linux system.